# Copy table into WPF RichTextBox loosing borders

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, rtf

I generate a `FlowDocument` with a `Table` and replace a `Selection` inside a WPF RTF box.

But the inserted table uses the last used `BorderSettings` for all cells. If I load the generated XAML inside a `FlowDocumentPageViewer` all looks fine.

Viewer:
[image]

Wrong RTF:
[image]

Please ignore the other formatting, only the `Border`s are my problem, the last `Border` is the underline, but in RTF it overwrites all other `CellBorders` and `Color` in the table.

Code:

```cs
//GetTable returns the Table
FlowDocument tmp_rtf_tabelle_test =new FlowDocument(((Datenblock_Mitte_Tabelle_Typ5)obj).GetTable());
              
TextRange tr_tabelle = new TextRange(tmp_rtf_tabelle_test.ContentStart,tmp_rtf_tabelle_test.ContentEnd);         

MemoryStream ms_tabelle = new MemoryStream();
                       
//if Dataformats XAML or rtf make no difference
tr_tabelle.Save(ms_tabelle, DataFormats.Xaml);                           
                   
rtf_vorschau.Selection.Load(ms_tabelle, DataFormats.Xaml);
ms_tabelle.Close();
```

Here's the generated XAML:

```xml
<Section
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xml:space="preserve" TextAlignment="Justify" LineHeight="Auto" IsHyphenationEnabled="False" xml:lang="en-us" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" NumberSubstitution.CultureSource="Text" NumberSubstitution.Substitution="AsCulture" FontFamily="Georgia" FontStyle="Normal" FontWeight="Normal" FontStretch="Normal" FontSize="16" Foreground="#FF000000" Typography.StandardLigatures="True" Typography.ContextualLigatures="True" Typography.DiscretionaryLigatures="False" Typography.HistoricalLigatures="False" Typography.AnnotationAlternates="0" Typography.ContextualAlternates="True" Typography.HistoricalForms="False" Typography.Kerning="True" Typography.CapitalSpacing="False" Typography.CaseSensitiveForms="False" Typography.StylisticSet1="False" Typography.StylisticSet2="False" Typography.StylisticSet3="False" Typography.StylisticSet4="False" Typography.StylisticSet5="False" Typography.StylisticSet6="False" Typography.StylisticSet7="False" Typography.StylisticSet8="False" Typography.StylisticSet9="False" Typography.StylisticSet10="False" Typography.StylisticSet11="False" Typography.StylisticSet12="False" Typography.StylisticSet13="False" Typography.StylisticSet14="False" Typography.StylisticSet15="False" Typography.StylisticSet16="False" Typography.StylisticSet17="False" Typography.StylisticSet18="False" Typography.StylisticSet19="False" Typography.StylisticSet20="False" Typography.Fraction="Normal" Typography.SlashedZero="False" Typography.MathematicalGreek="False" Typography.EastAsianExpertForms="False" Typography.Variants="Normal" Typography.Capitals="Normal" Typography.NumeralStyle="Normal" Typography.NumeralAlignment="Normal" Typography.EastAsianWidths="Normal" Typography.EastAsianLanguage="Normal" Typography.StandardSwashes="0" Typography.ContextualSwashes="0" Typography.StylisticAlternates="0">
    <Table Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1">
        <Table.Columns>
            <TableColumn Width="300" />
            <TableColumn Width="419" />
        </Table.Columns>
        <TableRowGroup>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell ColumnSpan="2" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" BorderBrush="#FFFF0000">
                    <Paragraph Background="#FFD3D3D3">
                        <Run> 5. Weitere Vorgehensweise</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="1,0,0,0" BorderBrush="#FF0000FF">
                    <Paragraph LineHeight="1" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <Run> Haftung:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#FFFFFF00">
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>&lt;Bitte wählen&gt;</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run> Deckung:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>&lt;Bitte wählen&gt;</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run> Plausibilität:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>&lt;Bitte wählen&gt;</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run> Zahlung in €:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>0,00</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run> Reserve in €:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>0,00</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run> Unterlagen folgen:</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
                <TableCell>
                    <Paragraph>
                        <Run>&lt;Bitte wählen&gt;</Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow>
                <TableCell ColumnSpan="2">
                    <Paragraph Margin="3,3,3,3">
                        <Run></Run>
                    </Paragraph>
                </TableCell>
            </TableRow>
        </TableRowGroup>
    </Table>
</Section>
```

UPDATE: I created a RTF file with the `Tables` and loaded them (FileStream), but the result is the same. `BorderSettings` are lost.

Comment: What do mean `RichTextBox` loosing borders? After loading the XAML mentioned above the `RichTextBox` doesn't include the red border displayed on the first screenshot?

Comment: yes, and all cells become the yellow Border 0,0,0,1

Comment: It is very strange. Because I do the same and everything works: the `Load()` creates exactly table described in the XAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the problem description when loading the Rich Text Format (RTF) document, that includes table with colored borders, the borders loses color and displayed in black.

> Let suppose the original `.rtf` document includes the following
> table with yellow cell borders:

[image]

> After loading this document to the `RichTextBox` control the table
> will look like below:

[image]

Unfortunately this is a known limitation of displaying `.rtf` documents prepared with the Microsft Word in WPF `RichTextBox` control.

The MSDN Community Support person wrote:

> I load the rtf document and displayed in WPF `RitchTextBox`, it lost
> part of the format (Open Normal with Word). If you want to open it
> with WPF RitchTextBox, I recommend using WPF `RitchTextBox` to save
> RTF files open to ensure consistent format. You can Load, Edit and
> Save Rich Text Format in WPF. Some styles may be lost through tool
> conversion.

For more information see article on the Microsoft site: [rtf document displayed in RitchTextBox display wrong colors](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6f506e91-471b-4891-b2e4-efd88c8e120e/rtf-document-displayed-in-ritchtextbox-display-wrong-colors?forum=wpf)

Comment: Please open the rtf https://wetransfer.com/downloads/126c19ba92332b444e54b813d1f07eef20201104165716/b71dc6 in Word and in wpf rtb the table on the end should show the Problem

Comment: this XAML was only a example for better reading, normally i use rtf, but result is the same

Comment: yes i load the rtf with  Dateitemplate_org =new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(Datei)); and than:  Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox rtf_vorschau = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.RichTextBox();
           
 Dateitemplate_org.Position = 0;
            rtf_vorschau.Selection.Load(Dateitemplate_org, DataFormats.Rtf); -> and all tableborders are black (when u use the uploaded rtf) (using normal wpf rtf and not xceed is the same result)

Comment: Thank u, but if i create the table during runtime (in a other wpf rtb), all is fine, until i copy (Selection.save/load (saved rtf or Xaml is ok)) it into the "main" wpf rtb (after copy the full table is yellow), so its not only a Word problem?

Comment: @user3600403: This is that described in the post:  [rtf document displayed in RitchTextBox display wrong colors](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6f506e91-471b-4891-b2e4-efd88c8e120e/rtf-document-displayed-in-ritchtextbox-display-wrong-colors?forum=wpf). The MSDN Community Support person wrote:  **If you want to open it with WPF RitchTextBox, I recommend using WPF RitchTextBox to save RTF files open to ensure consistent format.** I would like to help you more if you will provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)